# Why is a freefall trajectory the slowest path to the singularity of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

Back in June 2007, a Belgian newspaper reported on an article from Nature from 2 Sydney University astrophysicists named Geraint Lewis and Juliana Kwan, who claimed that once you passed the event horizon, any resistance will only make you reach the singularity faster. According to them, you can delay crashing into the singularity by a few minutes if you use your engines to get into a freefall trajectory.

I found the original paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1029, but I'm somewhat struggling to understand it given that my knowledge of physics doesn't go much past high school science classes. Why exactly is this freefall trajectory the slowest path? according to the newspaper, it keeps you alive the longest, although I'm not sure how accurate that is with spaghettification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaghettification occurs as you get closer to the singularity which is inevitable once you pass the Schwartz Child radius, but if you move to try to keep away from the black hole then you will only achieve dilating your own time. As you move faster, approaching the speed of light, time for you will slow down so you will have experienced less time during your travel toward the singularity. This means that trying to move away from the black hole will only achieve slowing down your own time so you experience less total time before death.